# how to create GUID?

Tags: .net, asp.net, guid

how to create GUID in asp.net 3.5?

Answer (score 23):

```
System.Guid.NewGuid()
```

The complete doc is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Something else that may be nice to know along with guids is how to set the format of the guid string

```
' plain with nothing added

Console.Writeline(System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"))

'with delimeter (-)/default 

Console.Writeline(System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D"))

'default with brackets

Console.Writeline(System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B"))

'default with paranthesis

Console.Writeline(System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("P"))
```

Answer (score 4):

System.Guid.NewGuid()